# Why does my unit test run successfully in the R console but returns an error with "make test"?

Tags: unit-testing, r

I am learning how to develop an R package. Everything goes well, thanks to the R manuals and [this](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=developers:runit) wiki for RUnit. More precisely, when I launch my unit tests within a new R console, all tests finish successfully:

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(RUnit)
testSuite <- defineTestSuite("current", "~/src/mypkg/inst/unitTests/")
isValidTestSuite  # returns TRUE
runTestSuite(testSuite)  # returns Number of errors: 0 and Number of failures: 0
```

However, when I launch them in a terminal, I got one error (the function in question uses the package [GenomicRanges](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) that I installed in "~/src/Rlibs"):

```
$ make test R_LIBS="~/src/Rlibs/"
...
ERROR in test.MyFunction: Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

I don't see what is causing this error. I guess you will need more info about the code and the test, but it's not easy because I don't know how to replicate this error on a small example without making a new package just for this. Maybe some of you will have an idea about this error message and give me some hints?

**Edit:** to help someone to give me a hint on the error, here is the code I wrote for a dummy package. The aim is to find which items of "p" are included within items of "g".

Here is the test:

```
test.MyFunction <- function(){
  g <- list(c1=data.frame(name=c("g1","g2"), start=c(11,1111),
                  end=c(500,1500), strand=c("+","+"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
  p <- list(c1=data.frame(name=c("p1","p2"), strand=c("+","-"),
                   start=c(11,601), end=c(20, 610), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
  exp <- list(c1=list(g1=c("p1")))  # item "p1" is included in item "g1"
  obs <- MyFunction(g, p)
  checkEquals(obs, exp)
}
```

And here is the function itself:

```
MyFunction <- function(g, p){
  res <- lapply(names(g), function(c.name){
    res.c <- list()
    nb.g <- length(g[[c.name]]$name)

    if(length(.find.package("GenomicRanges", quiet=TRUE)) > 0){
      g.ranges <- GRanges(seqnames=Rle(c(c.name), c(nb.g)),
                            ranges=IRanges(g[[c.name]]$start,
                              g[[c.name]]$end, names=g[[c.name]]$name),
                            strand="*")
      p.ranges <- GRanges(seqnames=Rle(c(c.name), nrow(p[[c.name]])),
                             ranges=IRanges(p[[c.name]]$start,
                               p[[c.name]]$end, names=p[[c.name]]$name),
                             strand=p[[c.name]]$strand)
      for(g.name in names(g.ranges)){
        links <- p.ranges %in% g.ranges[names(g.ranges) == g.name]
        if(sum(links) > 0)
          res.c[[g.name]] <- names(p.ranges)[which(links)]
      }
    } else{
      msg <- "can't find package GenomicRanges"
      stop(msg, call.=FALSE)
    }
    res.c
  })

  names(res) <- names(g)
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it may be caused by something in your `.Rprofile`. You could try running `R --vanilla` and see if it behaves differently.

Comment: @Owen I tried but it doesn't work either. In fact, if I launch it like that, I can't even use --vanilla because R needs to read at least my ~/.Renviron to find the package GenomicRanges (via the env variable R_LIBS).

Comment: Could you tell us what type of object is returned by `GRanges()`? ie, the output of `str(p.ranges)`, `str(g.ranges)`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen the output of str(g.ranges) is too big to be shown here, but here is the beginning: Formal class 'GRanges' [package "GenomicRanges"] with 7 slots -> (1) @ seqnames: Formal class 'Rle' [package "IRanges"] with 5 slots, (2) @ ranges: Formal class 'IRanges' [package "IRanges"] with 6 slots, (3) @ strand: Formal class 'Rle' [package "IRanges"] with 5 slots, (4) @ seqinfo: Formal class 'Seqinfo' [package "GenomicRanges"] with 3 slots, (5) @ elementMetadata: Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "IRanges"] with 6 slots, (6) @ elementType: chr "ANY", and (7) @ metadata: list().

Answer (score 7):

I think this line is your culprit:

`links <- p.ranges %in% g.ranges[names(g.ranges) == g.name]`.

`%in%` is `match`, and that is what the error message seems to be reading:

```
ERROR in test.MyFunction: Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

There is something about `p.ranges` and `g.ranges` that it doesn't like. I.e., they can't be coerced to vectors OR you're not subsetting properly and the object type is incorrect (`[` or `[[`).

Comment: thanks, I will see what I can do to change this specific line, but it's still unclear to me why this line works when executed interactively in the R console, but not otherwise...

Comment: I've seen this error before. It happens to me when I run line-by-line code vs. inside a function. It's always something to do with passing the wrong object class to a function that doesn't understand it. The error message says it all, and from what I can see - this is the only line that uses %in% aka match.